# Qt: Correct implementation of floating widgets

Tags: qt, widget

I've inherited my class from QWidget. Basically no extra code, just changes with the editor.

The way I use it:

```
focusWidget = new FocusWidget(this); //this points to the mainWindow
focusWidget->show();
focusWidget->hide();
```

Now the widget appears like this (it now looks ugly because of the bad 4k scaling), at the top left corner of the mainWindow.
I intend to use my application mostly full screen.

[image: Tool widget]

Is this usage correct?

How can I make it a floating widget?

If I want multiple widgets like that, how can I control their position?